# Android ViewFlipper blank screen after showNext

Tags: android

I have strange problem when using ViewFlipper. After I call ViewFlipper.showNext(); I got blank screen. When I sent activity to background and reopen it, view is shown as expected. This happens on AVD emulator API 15, same code on API 10 works as expected. I cannot test this issue on real device as I have only API 8 device.

My code look like this:

```
ViewFlipper vf = findViewById(R.id.viewFliper1);
vf.invalidate();
vf.showNext();
methodcall-it sets some TextView inside shown view
```

I tried almost all combination of invalidate, shownext and method call order and still no success. As this work in API level 10 AVD and not in API level 15 AVD I'm not sure if this AVD bug or my problem.

Maybe information that ViewFlipper is part of TabHost is useful for solving this problem for you...

Thanks in advance...